# convergence of function in $L^1$ metric

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that 
$$
  f_n(x) = \left\{  
    \begin{array}{cc}
      (1-\frac{2}{n})-(n-2)x & \text{if}\; 0\le x \le \frac{1}{n} \\
      0 & \text{if} \;\frac{1}{n}\le x  \le 1 
    \end{array}\right.$$
converges to 
$$
  g(x) = \left\{  
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & \text{if}\; x = 0 \\
      0 & \text{if} \;\text{otherwise} 
    \end{array}\right.$$
where $L^1$ metric is defined to be 
$$\int_0^1 \left|f(x) -g(x) \right| dx $$
I could show that $f_n \rightarrow g$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ when $x\in (0,1]$. But the problem is when $x=0$.
Can I just say that as integration is continuous case, the integration at $x\in[0,1]$ is equivalent to when $x\in(0,1]$?

Alternatively, I have tried to show 
$\left|f_n(0) - g(0) \right| <\varepsilon$. I think this is wrong because $\left|\cdot \right|$ is Euclidean matric, not $L^1$ matric.

Comment: Think you need an integration interval from 0 to 1. There's no pointwise convergence in your metric, so the value at a single point (like x=0) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute $\|f_n-g\|_{L^1}=\|f_n\|_{L^1}$. The graph of the function $f_n$ is a triangle with $f_n(0)=1-2/n$ and $f_n(1/n)=0$. Thus $$\|f_n\|_{L^1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2n}.$$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^1}=0$ and the claim follows.

Comment: Yes, This is what I have done, so it is not necessary to show that $|f_n(0)-g(0)|_{L^1} = |2/n|_{L^1} =0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.?

Comment: You don't need to plug in $x=0$ at all. The $L^1$ metric integrates out the $x$ dependence.